# PHP persistent replacing space characted at the end of my post value

Tags: php, post

I have a post value that contain space `' '` at the end like this:

```
<input name="code" type="text" value="test1 " />
```

the value is dynamic , sometimes it will contain whitespace at the end and sometimes it will not contain whitespace at the end

```
<input name="code" type="text" value="test2" />
```

when i retrieve the post data like this:

```
print_r($POST); 
//$_POST["code"] = "test"
```

the space at the end of value is gone, how to keep this space at the end of the value?

Comment: why you want to keep that space ?. you can trim($_POST['code']) to trim the space within the variable.

Comment: @Brain90 - maybe the OP likes/needs/wants it? ... lol

Answer (score 0):

You can add : `value="test&nbsp;"` in input field. `&nbsp;` post as a space

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question.  What I think you mean is that when the space is missing you want to add one in?  PHP won't automatically trim that space off, so it's the only thing I can think you mean.

For exmple:

```
if(isset($_POST["code"])) $_POST["code"] = rtrim( $_POST["code"] ).' ';
```

Trim any spaces from the right, then add one space. If there was no space it gets a space, if there was, it gets removed and a new one added.  Which has the effect of always having a space at the end.

Simple.